# MySQL: How to update key column starting with "1"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering how an elegant solution for this issue could look like:

I have a table with approx. 100 entries and one primary key column which has auto increment enabled. The keys start at 200.

Now I would like to disable the auto increment feature and update the key column so that the keys start at "1". Of course, I could just create a second table and just select/insert these values.

But I would like to know whether it is possible to update the key values directly. As the current keys start at 200 and there are less values, it should work somehow, right?

Comment: but why do you want to do that? Tell us the actual problem, not a perceived solution.

Comment: maybe something like `UPDATE table SET col = col-200`

Comment: I cant find a single reason for why would anyone want to do that,besides aesthetic issues.But one way is to drop the column,rest the autoincrement and recreate it again.

Comment: Is this yet another "gap" problem with MySQL's auto increment? Just to answer your question - yes, you *can* do it. But you should **never** do it. Just don't ever touch the value of primary key yourself. It's the same as pointing a gun to your foot and pulling the trigger. Yes, you can do it. Is it smart? - No it isn't. Is it needed? - No it isn't.

Comment: Hm, thanks for all your comments. I think, you are right. Have a nice sunday!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why do you need to do like this.I think these queries will work

```
SET @INDEX = 0;
UPDATE `tablename1` SET ID = (@INDEX:=@INDEX+1);

ALTER TABLE `tablename1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

AUTO_INCREMENT is set as 100 to update for next row. you need to set AUTO_INCREMENT with correct value in your query to generate ID that the way you want.